# Converting a html template containing highcharts to pdf

Tags: django, highcharts, reportlab, xhtml2pdf

I have a html template with highcharts in it.I have to mail these reports after converting to pdf.I tried to use xhtml2pdf but it just loads everything but the charts.Here is my code (view.py)

```
from io import BytesIO
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
from schedule.settings import EMAIL_HOST_USER
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage


def sender1(request):
userid = request.user.email
template = get_template('html.html')
context = {
    'pagesize': 'A3',
    }  
html = template.render(context)
result = BytesIO()

pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)

email = EmailMessage('Sub', 'schedule body testing', EMAIL_HOST_USER, [userid])

email.attach('report.pdf', result.getvalue(), 'application/pdf')
email.send()
```

my django template looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<script src="{% static 'node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.src.js' %}"></script>

<style type="text/css">
        @page {
            size: {{ pagesize }};
          }
        
    </style>
  </head>
 <body>
<div id="container1"></div>
<script>
Highcharts.chart('container1', {
  chart: {
      type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
      text: 'xyz'
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
},
  xAxis: {
      categories: [

       'tom','ron','Alex','John'
      ]
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
        animation: false,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
},

  series: [{
      name: 'A',
      data: [1,2,3,3],
    },{
      name: 'b',
      data: [2,5,6,8],
 }]
 });
</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

please help if there's any alternative to xhtml2pdf which can do this or with any modification which i should do to make xhtml2pdf work.

Comment: highcharts require javascript to generate its charts. since you are sending email from backend this template never gets rendered in a browser and the script is never executed so the chart is not generated. this is why you cannot see the charts in email.

Comment: Is there any way i can do it.. Will using javascript delay help....?(i am asking this and not implementing cuz i dont know how to pass it as a parameter in xhtml2pdf).

Comment: And thanks for ur response. Also previously i was using cdn for highcharts and thought that is causing the problem so later i downloaded it as static files .

Comment: I am afraid that Highcharts doesn't support any solution for this case. Have you considered to set up your own export server? https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside

Comment: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10146      this says xhtml2pdf was able to include highcharts

Comment: @SebastianWędzel I tried doing that but dont know what should be the structure of --infile.json